# Is it normal for a 2-year-old son to like hitting, biting and fighting?

Tags: toddler, behavior, violence

My son is two years old now. Somehow he likes fighting. His mornings start with hitting and biting. I know for him it's a game and he enjoys it. Also, sometimes he becomes angry and throws whatever is in his hand.

As of now I don't have a problem, but is this normal behavior for kids? Should I try to stop responding to him when he fights?

Comment: [Related](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/466/420)

Comment: [Also related](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7047/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-a-16-month-old-who-started-hitting?lq=1).

Comment: My 2 year old does exactly the same thing. Usually I give him a time-out or if he throws a tantrum just a small(light) hiding (only one hit) on his bum then he stops (when he's on diapers it was the sound of the diaper), now just to know that you are serious about what you are saying. But, I don't recommend giving hiding if you don't believe in this (I was brought up with hidings and that is how I learned), but each child is different.... Think this is just a fase they are in checking their limits....

Answer (score 3):

My son (just turned 5) was like that, and he eventually grew out of it.

We took a couple different approaches. On the punishment side, we'd go with time-out, or isolation in his room; we felt that giving him a lot of interaction for his bad behavior would just be rewarding it. (He has two older sisters, so it didn't particularly surprise us that he would decide that "bad attention is better than no attention.")

On the training side, we would teach him some alternative behaviors, like blowing instead of biting. To be honest, other people found the blowing bothersome too, but in our view it was miles better than biting.

In general we found that if we gave him a ton of attention, that would keep his behavior good, but of course sometimes (especially with the other kids) that just isn't possible.

If the behavior lasts into preschool (it did for us), it will cause problems with the other kids, teachers and parents. You will want to pick the school carefully.