Toddler hitting baby sibling
I have a 2.5 year old non-verbal son who is not yet diagnosed but most likely has ASD.
I am having issues with his meltdowns, his listening and comprehension skills, and him hitting, pushing and generally being mean to his 8month old baby sibling. I feel the main issue that sort of rides over all the problems we're having is that he doesn't listen when we try to explain things, or can't understand. If we ever have to say no he melts down. If we ask him to do something he doesn't want to do he melts down. If I'm ever trying to explain anything to him he melts down. So it's like I'm talking to a brick wall. I hit my breaking point when I saw him pushing his sister's face into the floor, this is after constantly pushing her over, aggressively covering her with a rug which scares her, snatching things from her.
I always try to say, gentle with bay sister. Cuddles only for baby sister but it just doesnt work. I dont think he understands and I have no way of knowing if he does or not.
Any advice please.

https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/466/how-do-you-discourage-a-toddler-from-hitting-people?rq=1

This question is similar to: How do you discourage a toddler from hitting people?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If your son had ASD, you can use a lot more guidance than can be provided in a simple answer here. Have the child tested (why wait?) and start working with professionals.

@BartvanIngenSchenau - The question may be similar, but the answers are questionable.

@anongoodnurse Just wondering do you have a child with ASD? We take our son to speech therapy and occupational therapy, the process of getting a diagnosis involves a lot of waiting, the systems are less than easy to work with.

I understand that it's (very) frustrating working within bureaucracies. But not being familiar with your child means the answers you might get will be of limited relevance. If you yourself don't know the level of his understanding, how can we possibly give good advice? If he understands, and it's just jealousy (very common, and relatively easy to deal with in ways the child will understand), that answer will be very from one involving much more limited understanding and ability to control oneself. One would need to ask a lot of questions to know the difference. ...

I have dealt with some pretty significant sibling rivalry, and I found that time-outs as described in detail in 1,2,3 Magic worked very well in my family, but my kids were mostly neurotypical (I have one who is mildly neurodiverse. That child was by far the most difficult to... teach/encourage towards prosocial behavior. They still have issues.) (error in prev. comment, should read "...answer will be very differentfrom...")

@anongoodnurse Thanks for your advice. I'm interested in the book and will give it a read! As much as I need to curb his behaviours, I'm realising my responses to his behaviours are less than ideal and I need to work on that too - just tough when you're in the grind and it never ends! Having some proven strategies to work with might help things so thanks for that

@Worriedmum - I loved the book's no-conflict-no-escalation approach. And we all do the best we can; two little ones those ages is a lot, trust me, I've been there. That approach reduced the conflict in our family at least 95% (between my kids and I, but not them and their father, because their father didn't apply it correctly.) When understood and followed, tempers were not tested. Good luck!
